# MYSQL Average N rows

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a MYSQL DB with the following data
ID,
TEMP,
log_time

Each record has a unique value of ID, log_time is generated automatically with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
TEMP is a float that is inserted example 29.90

I can select the most recent data using

```
SELECT ID, TEMP, log_time FROM log_data 
WHERE ID = (select max(ID) from log_data)
```

How can I average the most recent 60 values for TEMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to sort the top 60 rows by `log_time` in descending order. And then find the average of `TEMP`.

**Query**

```
select avg(t.TEMP) as average_temp from
(
    select ID, TEMP, log_time
    from log_data
    order by log_time desc limit 60
)t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select avg(new.TEMP) from
(
    select *
    from table
    order by log_time desc limit 60
) new
```

select 60 records with `limit 60` for latest record use `order by desc`

Comment: It will not limit the result of avg()